# BinaryFormatter determine type of object in OnDeserializingMethod

Tags: c#, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have a very complex csla object. This object has been serialized to Database in binary. One of the child objects changes and I cannot deserialize the object anymore. (When I try to deserialize it, the properties contain junk or are not initialized because the deserialization did'nt work in the new class.) I'll post a simplified example here.

```
    [serializable]
public class Head : BusinessBase<Head>
  {
    private static PropertyInfo<int> _eyesCountProperty = RegisterProperty<int>(new PropertyInfo<int>("EyesCount")); 

    public int EyesCount 
    {
    get { return GetProperty(_eyesCountProperty ); }
    set { SetProperty(_eyesCountProperty , value); }
    }
  }

    [serializable]
  public class Person : BusinessBase<Person>
  {
    private static PropertyInfo<string> _firstNameProperty = RegisterProperty<string>(new PropertyInfo<string>("FirstName")); 

    public string FirstName
    {
    get { return GetProperty(_firstNameProperty ); }
    set { SetProperty(_firstNameProperty , value); }
    }
  }
    public Head MyHead { get; set; }
  }
```

So let's say I have an instance of "Person" class and I serialize it to the database.
Here's our serializing and deserializing methods.

```
public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(object theObject)
{
  byte[] result = null;
  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
  using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    bf.Serialize(ms, theObject);
    result = ms.ToArray();
  }

  return result;
}

public static object ConvertFromByteArray(byte[] serializedObject)
{
  object result = null;
  using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(serializedObject))
  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    result = bf.Deserialize(ms);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now let's say that the Head class changes and I now have the noseCount and mouthCount in it. So I try to rename it as "HeadV1" and create a "HeadV2" class with the new properties in it. (I would need to do a "PersonV1" class with the "HeadV1" property and a "PersonV2" class with the "HeadV2".)

In the PersonV2 class, I would like to have an "OnDeserializing" method that would let me know if the item I'm trying to deserialize is of type "PersonV1" or "PersonV2" in order to deserialize it the right way.

```
 [OnDeserializing()]
internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
  // Determine if data is of type "PersonV1" or "PersonV2"
}
```

But I'm stuck, I don't know how to do it and I can't seem to find how to do it. Is there any way to do so? I don't seem to have access to the data inside the "OnDeserializing" method?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but just to throw out some ideas... how about using a second database field to store the data type independently of the serialized object?  How about making all of your types conform to an Interface that has a property that holds the datatype?  You could deserialize as an IWhatever to access the property, and then deserialize a second time as the specific class type if you needed to.  You could also try deserializing to a Dynamic or ExpandoObject or something and then you could examine the properties before working with them.

Comment: Those are some good ideas! Thanks I'll try it out on Monday :-)